# Phonegap: Asynchronous calls in javascript or native code?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-asynctask

I'm developing a prototipe Phonegap application for Android where I have a couple of (xml) lists that are fetched through restful in the "Java layer". Fetching and parsing these lists might take a little while. I was running everything in the UI thread but decided to take the next step and move this processing to a AsyncTask subclass and everything works "asynchronously fine". My question is, is it really valid using AsyncTask or should I somehow (haven't exactly thought of how yet) call the Cordova exec functions asynchronously? The reason I ask that is for we'll also end up developing the same application for iOS and WP (hence the use of Phonegap) and I figured that if I code asynchronous calls in Java, I'll also have to code them in C# and Objective-C. But if it is possible to make it run asynchronously through Javascript/jQuery, wouldn't it be better, since it would save me time when coding to the other platforms? Like I said before, it works fine with AsyncTask and I'm not quite sure if it's even possible to achieve the same behavior with JS/jQ only (I'm nowhere near what you'd call an expert on those two) but should it be, is it a valid approach or JS would end up becoming a bottleneck?

PS: I know that using AsyncTask is staple for Android but I don't know how the other two behave (yet).

Comment: Why would you not just use AJAX to fetch your XML files in JavaScript? That way you wouldn't need to re-write stuff for each platform.

Comment: Like I said before, I'm just getting started with JS, I know the basics, but I didn't know I could do that with Ajax. I'll look around and try to figure out how to do it and give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify them to be synchronous, AJAX request in JavaScript are inherently asynchronous. You should be looking to use AJAX functionality to perform these tasks. Even if you plan to do something native with the result of the ReST response, it would reduce the amount of native code to use JavaScript to perform the ReST request.

Since you said you're relatively new to JS and jQuery here are some references to start learning about AJAX. Any questions you have beyond that should be thoroughly covered somewhere on SO.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Like I said in my reply to Simon, I didn't know that AJAX could make a request to a Rest service. But not only you pointed me to the right direction as you answered my main question as well, thanks Nick! =)